# How to write dynamica CSS in Qwik?

Tags: qwik

I have this code in Next.js:

```
        <div
            className={"bg-white origin-top transition-all duration-300 absolute z-50 w-full"}
            style={isOpen ? {} : { transform: 'rotateX(90deg)' }}
        >
```

As you can see, I'm using `style` attribute to conditionally apply some CSS on an element. The `isOpen` is a state here.

How can I write it for Qwik. I tried the following and it did not work:

```
        <div
            class={"bg-white origin-top transition-all duration-300 absolute z-50 w-full"}
            style={isOpen ? {} : { transform: 'rotateX(90deg)' }}
        >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have conditional style with [Signals](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/state/#usesignal)

Here is an example:

```
style={`${
  isOpenSig.value ? {} : { transform: 'rotateX(90deg)' }
}`}
```

Here is a similar question for class https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76452479/edit